# Is there a way to have multiple versions of glibc in the same system?

Tags: debian, glibc

I tried to install different versions of `glibc` (debian) but in the end my system collapsed. I know there's a tool called [Modules](http://modules.sourceforge.net/) but that's not exactly what I'm looking for, I need to have software which depends on different versions of `glibc` to coexist.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Multiple glibc libraries on a single host](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/847179/multiple-glibc-libraries-on-a-single-host)?

Answer (score 1):

Just to leave a trace :) I solved the problem successfully (until now) using  Debian's *pinning*. Explained in section "8.2.1 Pinning releases with APT" of the book *The Debian System - by Martin Krafft*.

Basically, it consists in creating the file `/etc/apt/preferences` assigning priorities to a Package (`libc` in my case)

```
Package: *
Pin: release a=stable
Pin-Priority: 900
Package: *
Pin: release a=testing
Pin-Priority: 90
Package: *
Pin: release a=unstable
Pin-Priority: 80
```

And modifying `/etc/apt/sources.list`

I highly recommend reading that section of the book ;)